Label index and refer to it
In my document using the amsbook class. I need to include an index of notation.
For that, I'm using makeidx, as explained in the package documentation.
Now, I would like to refer to it in the text, but I can't find a way to label it.
The idea is to create a clickable reference, as I'm using hyperref, and not just write something like see Index of notation.
How could I do it?
Thanks
EDIT: I don't want to refer to any particular entry of the index, but to the whole section, as in See \ref{idx} for all the details about notation.
MWE:
\documentclass[makeidx]{amsbook}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\title{mwe}
\author{ME}
\date{June 2024}


\makeindex
\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}

We define $N$ as the notation.
\index{N@$N$, notation}

\chapter{Second}

See \ref{idx} for a detailed list with the notation we will use in this document.



\backmatter
\printindex
\label{idx}

\end{document}


Index of notation is not really what we normally refer to as an index (the package doc you refer to). I'd look up the glossaries package instead. It can build this index of notation and lt you add page numbers to it be refering in the text. The index works in the other direction, it is build from \index commands you add in the text. That does not seem to be what you want to do here.

@daleif I've already created all the references for this makeindex, so I'd appreciate it if I didn't have to change packages. And I don't want to refer to any particular entry, but to the whole section itself. Something like See \ref{idx}.

Alternative to glossaries for making a kind of glossary or list of acronyms or symbols are also available, e.g. acro, and several of them work with hyperref. However, if you want to use makeidx read section "13.2 Index with makeindex" in the hyperref manual.

makeidx also allows to distinguish the shown and the sorted entry. So maybe you could do the linking using the actual (usually @) to add \hyperanchor etc. But without minimal working example that shows, what you've tried to far, it is hard to answer, how you can improve it. So this is only a guess.

@cabohah Ok, I'll add a mwe

IMHO much clearer now.

Note: You are writing, that you are using hyperref, but the example does not show the usage of hyperref. Nevertheless, I've added it to my example below.
The index is a not numbered chapter. But \ref{…} usually refers to a number — for chapter to the chapter number. So a \ref{idx} does not make sense. For not numbered chapters, I would recommend to use \nameref instead. So you just need to add a \label{…} to the index. Class amsbook uses \indexchap for the index, so something like:
\documentclass[makeidx]{amsbook}

\title{mwe}
\author{ME}
\date{June 2024}

\makeindex

\AddToHook{cmd/indexchap/after}{\label{idx}}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}

We define $N$ as the notation.
\index{N@$N$, notation}

\chapter{Second}

See \nameref{idx} on \pageref{idx} for a detailed list with the notation we will use in this document.



\backmatter
\printindex

\end{document}

could be used to have the \label automatically added.
With hyperref also using \autopageref instead of \pageref would make sense:
\documentclass[makeidx]{amsbook}

\title{mwe}
\author{ME}
\date{June 2024}

\makeindex

\AddToHook{cmd/indexchap/after}{\label{idx}}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}

We define $N$ as the notation.
\index{N@$N$, notation}

\chapter{Second}

See \nameref{idx} on \autopageref{idx} for a detailed list with the notation we will use in this document.



\backmatter
\printindex

\end{document}


Note, adding \label after \printindex is not recommended, because it would refer to a place after the index. So a \pageref{…} would show the wrong page, if the index has more than one pages.
As an alternative to hook cmd/indexchap/after the more general hook cmd/theindex/after can also be used. This alternative would also work with, e.g., with the standard classes. And before someone ask: No, env/theindex/begin would not be better. It would add the \label too early.

Yes, you're right, I forgot to add the hyperref package, thanks.

You can combine a few things:

With hyperref you can create a target for things that are not linkable by themselves using the \phantomsection command followed by a \label.
You can link to a page in the document with a custom text using \hyperlink{page.n}{custom text}
You can find the page number for a label using \getpagerefnumber from the refcount package.

MWE:
\documentclass[makeidx]{amsbook}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{refcount}

\title{mwe}
\author{ME}
\date{June 2024}


\makeindex
\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}

We define $N$ as the notation.
\index{N@$N$, notation}

\chapter{Second}

See \hyperlink{page.\getpagerefnumber{idx}}{Index of notation} for a detailed list with the notation we will use in this document.



\backmatter
\phantomsection
\label{idx}
\printindex

\end{document}

Result:

Sources:
Correct hyperlink to the index
Using \hyperlink to link text to page with an implicit page anchor not known in advance
